# Percentage of coverage of parent div using bootstrap without losing responsiveness

Tags: html, css, grid

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row heading">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h1> BLABLABLA </h1>
            <div class="row logos">
                <div class="col-md-4 logogit">
                    <!-- image git logo -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 logopdf">
                    <!-- another logo image -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 logolink">
                    <!-- another logo image -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- my picture -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so basically what I want to have is something like this:

/-----------h1 with background color -----/  / -------my picture ----/
/----col1 ---//----col2 ---//----col3 ---/

and of course I want the left section to have the same height with my picture, which means that I need the h1 background and the background of the logos to cover the full height of their parent div, which needs to be the same as my picture's height.

If, however, I set heading div to have a specific height (eg. 325px) and then set every other length with px heights, I am going to lose responsiveness.

So, finally, what is the way to manage to have the heading div have a specific height and then left and right section fit in it.

PS. Sorry if I can't make myself very clear!

Comment: You can set your parent div .row.heading to certain height in percentages. Then set the col-md-9 and col-md-3 to height: 100%. Whatever percentage you set for the .row.heading div the col-md-3 and 9 will fill its space.

Comment: Actually, if I simply set .heading to some specific height percentage (eg. 45%), nothing changes...

Comment: It does. Set the height, then open your inspector and find the .heading div and highlight it. http://screencast.com/t/KoXzS8Pc

Comment: Then set the other divs 100% and they will fill the space: http://screencast.com/t/4QAsyr82ToQ

Comment: Allright it's done! thank you!